# optimize stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have one question on how to optimized my sp, actually it was a view but I decided to change to sp to make it faster, and it did work. First it took 27 seconds for a view to run and 16 sec for sp. So it is getting better but how to make it even better?

Table that I am running my sp on is 600 records and I am returning around 80 fields and out of 80, 4 fields are images. They are not not too big around 400KB per record.

Any suggestion what can I do.

Comment: You'd have to show us the code...

Comment: Yeah. Really. Plus i doubt making it a sp was making it faster - you did another change that you are totally unaware of. Show us both code examples. 27 AND 16 seconds are freaking slow for data retrieval of 600 records. Like REALLY slow. And I doubt you need the 600 image bitmaps at that moment.

Comment: Echoing the above; 16 seconds seems like a looooong time, even if your query is needing to do a table scan including reading every byte of those images to test them against a predicate. We need to see not only code, but also to know a bit about the db structure. Of course.. 80 fields...

Comment: If all records are retrieved, it amounts to 240MB. 16 seconds is still a lot to retrieve 240MB but then again...

Comment: Well, my db in total is aroun 1Gb but the code is ntohing really. Select * from table and that is it also the sp I did the same way

Comment: Well I also agree that 80 field is not efficient for the design but I had to leave like that for other reasons                       When I did covered indexes it didn't allow me to select image fields.....all this problems started when I imported images...around 3200..some are 50kb and some 500

Comment: @Tony: the size of the DB doesn't matter.  The size of the rows returned does.  Returning 240MB of data is kind of.. well not the right thing to do.  The time taken will be seriously impacted by the underlying hardware (hard drive, memory, and network).  Return just the actual data you are going to use.  Bear in mind that you don't have to one One Query To Rule Them All... You can have different queries to do different things.

Comment: Thanks Chris, like I mentioned below and also to the person using the front-end application, but this is what happens when you do not have the db person working with you, then it is just waist of my time and effort

Answer (score 2):

you say you tried to use covering indexes, which is a good idea on a table that has 80 columns, including images.  However, you said that this didn't work with the images.  I would suggest that you split this table apart, even if you just make several 1 to 1 tables.  That "*" in `select * from ...` is not helping much.  Only return the columns you need.  Also, what about the `WHERE`?  While it is important to only return the columns you need, it is even more critical to only return the rows you need.  All the indexes in the world will not help if you have no `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks KM, I know, but I am responsible for SQL side and the application requires all the rows, I suggested to the persone using the front-end to fiter by one field but he wants to have everything, so I am stuck...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried implementing proper indexes for the query being called by the SPROC?
Also take a look at the execution plan and see what types of indexes can be best for the query.
Lastly, update table and index statistics and check fragmentation on indexes for any performance hits.

Comment: I tried to do indexes, I used non-cluster and covered index but no improvement, the same thing, 16 sec. I analized the table with the enging tuning advisor and no recomendation came up.

Answer (score 0):

> "Table that I am running my sp on is 600 records and I am returning around 80 fields and out of 80, 4 fields are images"

If I were you, I would have put images into file system and their indexed paths in database.

> ["Columns that are of the large object (LOB) data types ntext, text, varchar(max), nvarchar(max), varbinary(max), xml, or image cannot be specified as key columns for an index" as well as non-key (included) columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx)

Besides, I would have ascertain that images are [really cached by your webbrowser](http://www.ahinea.com/en/tech/ie-dhtml-image-caching.html)

Comment: Thanks vgv, but this is for SQL 2008?